# Erro "Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: java, android

Acredito que o erro ocorre devido à falta de memória. Recebo a seguinte exceção. Quando entro no aplicativo e minimizo o mesmo, depois entro em vários aplicativos minimizando os que foram abertos, volto para o aplicativo principal, dá o erro de "Aplicativo parou".

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AndroidExplorer/com.AndroidExplorer.MainTab}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3590)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
>       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1925)
>       at com.AndroidExplorer.MainTab.onCreate(MainTab.java:78)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
>       ... 12 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.AndroidExplorer.ClienteTab did not create a view.
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:295)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>       ... 23 more

Comment: O erro por si só não diz muita coisa. Posta o seu código (layouts, activities, fragment, etc). Alguma coisa pode ter sido mal implementada.

Comment: O erro apenas é pouco mas parece que não implementou correctamente o método `onCreateView()` do *fragment* ClienteTab.

Comment: Sim, Obrigado por responder

Comment: Coloquei algumas classes abaixo, do possível problema, não tiver um resultado esperado ainda. Talvez o problema ocorre ao reconstruir a tela.

Answer (score 0):

Classe: clienteTab.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("teste antes de inflar layout");
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clientetab, container, false);
    System.out.println("teste depois de inflar layout");

    // Define a imagem de fundo de acordo com a orientacao do dispositivo
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fundocadastro);
    else
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fundocadastro);

    instanciate();
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clientetab.xml

```
<TextView android:text="Entrevistado:" android:id="@+id/txtEntrevistado" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerEntrevistado" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Spinner>

<TextView android:id="@+id/txtUsuario" android:textSize="18dp" android:text="Usuário do imóvel:" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" > </TextView>
<EditText android:id="@+id/nomeUsuario" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" android:inputType="textCapCharacters" android:maxLength="50" ><requestFocus></requestFocus> </EditText>

<TextView android:text="Tipo de Pessoa:" android:id="@+id/txtTipo_pessoa" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerTipoPessoaUsuario" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Spinner>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <TextView android:text="CPF:" android:id="@+id/txtCpfCnpjUsuario" android:minWidth="180dp" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="RG:" android:id="@+id/txtRgUsuario" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/cpfCnpjUsuario" android:minWidth="150dp" android:maxLength="18" android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="number"></EditText>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/rgUsuario" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" android:inputType="number" android:maxLength="13" ></EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
    <TextView android:text="UF:" android:id="@+id/uf" android:minWidth="110dp" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="Sexo:" android:id="@+id/sexo" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/ufUsuario" android:minWidth="50dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:maxLength="2" android:inputType="textCapCharacters"></EditText>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerSexoUsuario" android:minWidth="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
    <TextView android:text="Telefone:" android:id="@+id/txtTelefone" android:minWidth="150dp" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="Celular:" android:id="@+id/txtCelular" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/foneUsuario" android:minWidth="150dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxLength="14" android:inputType="phone"></EditText>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/celularUsuario" android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxLength="14" android:inputType="phone"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:text="E-mail:" android:id="@+id/txtEmailUsuario" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
<EditText android:id="@+id/emailUsuario" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:maxLength="50" ></EditText>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout7">
    <TextView android:text="Usuário é proprietário do imóvel:" android:id="@+id/txtUsuarioEProprietario" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout8">
    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"    android:id="@+id/groupUsuarioEProprietario">
        <RadioButton android:text="Não" android:id="@+id/radioNao" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:text="Sim" android:id="@+id/radioSim" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTextoTipoEnderecoUsuario">
    <TextView android:text="Tipo de endereço do proprietário:" android:id="@+id/txtTipoEnderecoUsuario" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTipoEnderecoUsuario">
    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"    android:id="@+id/groupTipoEnderecoUsuario">
        <RadioButton android:text="Residencial" android:id="@+id/radioResidencial" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton android:text="Comercial" android:id="@+id/radioComercial" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutUsuarioEProprietario">
</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:text="Responsável pelo Pagamento:" android:id="@+id/responsavelPagamento" android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@color/textColor" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
<Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinnerDefineResponsavel" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Spinner>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutResponsavelPagamento">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout     android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPeriodo">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_text" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:ellipsize="end" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonSave" android:text="  OK  " android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="20dp" android:background="@drawable/button_rounded_corners" android:gravity="right" android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

mainTab

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.AndroidExplorer.ClienteTab"
        android:id="@+id/tabCliente"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.AndroidExplorer.ImovelTab"
        android:id="@+id/tabImovel"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.AndroidExplorer.ServicosTab"
        android:id="@+id/tabServicos"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.AndroidExplorer.AnormalidadeTab"
        android:id="@+id/tabAnormalidade"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```